# selenium remote webdriver: session times out after 5 minutes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have tried using following commands to start hub and node:

NODE: java -jar selenium-server.jar -role node -hub http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx -browserTimeout=9000 -timeout=9000

HUB: java -jar selenium-server.jar -role hub -timeout=9000 -browserTimeout=9000 -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=9000

But my browser driver on node quits after about 5 minutes with error "session xxxx deleted due to client timeout". Could you please help me here? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

to fix this issue you need to use this parameter on run **NODE**:

```
--session-timeout 500000
```

more information in documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/cli_options/

in docker-composer this issue is solved like this:

```
 ChromeService:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.5.0
    shm_size: "2gb"
    ports:
      - "5900"  
    environment:
      - SE_OPTS=--session-timeout 500000
    depends_on:
      - HubService
```